# Grammar refactoring for LL parsing

Tags: grammar, ll-grammar

In a simple example, I'm confused about how to turn this grammar into a LL one by removing the left recursion. Any hints are welcome.

```
G = {
      A -> A a | A B | a
      B -> b
    }
```

I get the following by applying [this algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion):

```
G = {
      A -> a X
      X -> e | A | B X
      B -> b
    }
```

This seem to work to generate a C pseudo-code for the parser:

```
void A() {
    switch (token) {
        case 'a' : next(); X(); break;
    }
}

void X() {
    switch (token) {
        case 'e' : finish(); break;
        case 'a' : A(); break;
        case 'b' : B(); X(); break;
    }
}

void B() {
    next();
}
```

And to generate a parsing tree for the word: `aabab`:

```
A ---+
|    |
a    X
     |
     A ---+
     |    |
     a    X ---+
          |    |
          B    X
          |    |
          b    A ---+
               |    |
               a    X ---+
                    |    |
                    B    X
                    |    |
                    b    e
```

Well, I'm just not sure if it's right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your grammar seems to accept sequences of `a`s separated by single `b`s, so that no 2 `b` come together. (`aaa...abaaaaa...abaaa...a`) This should be equivalent to something like:

```
Q -> P | P b P
P -> a | a P
```

Comment: Sorry for not saying. I need to maintain some structure of the original grammar. Take a look at the edit. =D

Comment: @Vinicius: well, the grammar you've presented (the second one) seems to be correct. The only changes in the pseudocode would be (1) default case in switches, producing an error, (2) `'e'` should be not a character but EOF or whatever marks the end of the input stream.